Query data from one table when a condition from another table is met
Currently I have a project in laravel but my programmer partner has disappeared and he is the one who is in charge of the heavy work, because I am less experienced.
I have a problem with a view, I have several tables:
1-Accounts
2-Users
3-Services
4-Subscriptions
5-Profiles
I have a view that generates subscriptions, which shows me through a select the services available in the system, then the accounts associated to the service and the User_id, then I can see the profiles that are associated to the accounts and that are available (that is to say that they have not been used), to be able to make a subscription of 1 Service in an account X, and a profile X of this account.
The situation I have is that I need that as well as it lists ONLY the profiles that are empty; then it lists only the accounts that have empty or available profiles. Well, when I choose an account that does not have available profiles, I have to select one by one the emails to see which one has available profiles.
This is the view of a new subscription
enter image description here
Services are listed
enter image description here
The accounts belonging to that service are displayed
enter image description here
Profiles available for the sample account pedro@gmail.com
enter image description here
For the case of the account jua01@gmail.com (no profiles in your name are available and therefore the profile list is empty)
enter image description here
What I need is to avoid the hassle of going account by account to see if it has free profiles or not. Inside my SubscriptionController I have these functions that go to this issue in question:
public function getAccounts($service_id){
    $data = [];
    $attr = [
        'table'=>'accounts',
        'columns'=>[
            'id',
            'email'
        ],
        'compare'=>'service_id',
        'compare_value'=>$service_id
    ];
    $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr,auth()->user()->id);
    if($response){
        $data = $response;
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
}

public function getProfiles($account_id){
    $data = [];
    $attr = [
        'table'=>'profiles',
        'columns'=>[
            'id',
            'name',
            'pin'
        ],
        'compare'=>'account_id',
        'compare_value'=>$account_id
    ];
    $response = Helper::getDataSelect($attr);
    if($response){
        foreach($response as $res){
            $profile = Profile::find($res->id);
            if($profile->subscriptions->count() == 0){
                array_push($data, $res);
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=>$data]);
}

Inside the Helper I have this function
public static function getDataSelect($attr,$user_id=null){
        if($attr){
            if($user_id){
                $data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
            }else{
                $data = DB::table($attr['table'])->select($attr['columns'])->where($attr['compare'],$attr['compare_value'])->get();
            }

            return $data;
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

And finally in my view I have a script that has to do with the selects
@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-success">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2><i class="fas fa-star"></i> {{ $title }}</h2>
                </div>
                @include('admin.partials.form', ['element'=>'subscriptions', 'type'=>$type, 'id'=>@$data->id])
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Servicio:</label>
                            <select name="service_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('service_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                    <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('service_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cuenta:</label>
                            <select name="account_id"  class="form-control form-control-sm @error('account_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1" >Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('account_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Perfil:</label>
                            <select name="profile_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('profile_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('profile_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Cliente:</label>
                            <select name="customer_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('customer_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option>Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($customers as $customer)
                                    <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}} ({{$customer->phone}})</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('customer_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Monto:</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount" class="form-control @error('amount') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('amount')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Instrumento:</label>
                            <select name="paymeth_id" class="form-control form-control-sm @error('paymeth_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <option value="-1">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach($paymeths as $paymeth)
                                    <option value="{{$paymeth->id}}">{{$paymeth->instrumento}} ({{$paymeth->moneySymbol}})</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('paymeth_id')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Referencia:</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="referencia" class="form-control @error('referencia') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('referencia')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Vencimiento:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_to" class="form-control @error('date_to') is-invalid @enderror" />
                            @error('date_to')
                               <span class="error invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        @include('admin.partials.buttons',['cancelRoute'=>'subscriptions.index'])
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('js')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").select2();
            $("select[name='service_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-accounts/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='account_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.email+"</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='account_id']").html("<option>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });

            $("select[name='account_id']").change(function(){
                let id = $(this).val();
                if(id != '-1'){
                    $.get('/admin/get-profiles/'+id, function(response){
                        let data = response.data;
                        if(data.length > 0){
                            $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(v,e){
                                $("select[name='profile_id']").append("<option value='"+e.id+"'>"+e.name+" ("+e.pin+")</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    $("select[name='profile_id']").html("<option value='-1'>Seleccione</option>");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@stop

I have tried a couple of things but I have no idea how to first collect the accounts that have those free profiles.

It is called a cascading dropdown
